# How does it work Observer confirmation?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

In the example, what does `of()` make? How does it work?

```
 public onRemoving(tag): Observable<any> {
    const confirm = window.confirm('Do you really want to remove this tag?');
    return Observable.of(tag).filter(() => confirm);
}
```

I tried adapt to my case:

```
const confirm = false;
this.mapDlg
      .confirm(args)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res != null) {
          confirm = true;
        }
      });

return Observable
      .of(tag)
      .filter(() => confirm);
```

But it does now work, `.confirm()` returns Observable where I catch value `confirm`

Also I tried to do this like:

```
public onRemoving(tag: any): Observable<any> {

    const args = new MultiDlgArgs();
    args.type = 'confirmation';

    return Observable.create(observer => {
      return this.mapDlg
        .confirm(args)
        .subscribe(res => {
          return false;
        });
    });
  }
```

Another way I have tried:

```
public onRemoving(tag: any): Observable<any> {

    const args = new MultiDlgArgs();
    args.type = 'confirmation';

    return new Observable<boolean>(observer => {

        this.mapDlg
          .confirm(args).map((res) => {
          if (res == null) {
            observer.next(false);
          } else {
            observer.next(true);
          }
        });

      }
    );
  }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may think about Observable as about constant stream of data, opposite to Promise that firing only once.
.of() - Creates an Observable that emits a sequence of numbers (or any other data) within a specified range. [docs](http://reactivex.io/rxjs/class/es6/Observable.js~Observable.html#static-method-of)

You probably need something like that:

```
this.mapDlg
      .confirm(args)
      .subscribe(res => {
        if (res != null) {
          Observable.create((observer)=> {
            observer.next(true);
        });
        }
      });
```

Comment: How to apply this to exist Observer function? I updated question

Comment: Jessie, Do you need return Observable or boolean value?

Comment: Yes, you are right, I get boolena value from another Observer and need to return this in Observer, Look at my question

Comment: This is right. And, by implication, the dialog API is poorly designed.

Comment: Andrew, I tried usign this example, aslo I need to use `of(tag)` look:

Comment: `public onRemoving(tag): Observable<any> {
        const confirm = window.confirm('Do you really want to remove this tag?');
        return Observable
            .of(tag)
            .filter(() => confirm);
    }`

Answer (score 1):

It create an Observable you can subscribe to.

You can see that the function is returning a variable typed as `Observable<any>`.

This is how I learnt to create Observable, not with the `Observable.create` method.